# SWIG: Access Array of Structs in Python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, linux, swig

Say I have the following `static constexpr` array of c struct:

```
#include <cstdint>

namespace ns1::ns2 {
    struct Person {
        char name[32];
        uint8_t age;    
    };
    static constexpr Person PERSONS[] = {
        {"Ken", 8},
        {"Cat", 27}
    };
}
```

How can I access elements in `ns1::ns2::PERSONS` in python by using swig?

One way I can think of is to create a accessor like `const Person& get(uint32_t index)` in the swig interface file.  Tho, I wonder whether there is a more elegant way that I don't have to create an accessor function for each array of c struct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One way I can think of is to create a accessor like const Person& get(uint32_t index) in the swig interface file.

According to [5.4.5 Arrays](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn26) in the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html), that's the way to do it:

```cpp
%module test

%include <stdint.i>

%inline %{
#include <cstdint>

namespace ns1::ns2 {
    struct Person {
        char name[32];
        uint8_t age;
    };
    static constexpr Person PERSONS[] = {
        {"Ken", 8},
        {"Cat", 27}
    };
}

// helper function
const ns1::ns2::Person* Person_get(size_t index) {
    if(index < sizeof(ns1::ns2::PERSONS) / sizeof(ns1::ns2::Person))  // protection
        return ns1::ns2::PERSONS + index;
    else
        return nullptr;
}
%}
```

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> test.PERSONS.name # can only access the first element
'Ken'
>>> test.Person_get(1).name
'Cat'
>>> test.Person_get(2).name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

SWIG can also generate array wrappers for you with [11.2.2 carrays.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_carrays), but there is no bounds checking:

```cpp
%module test

%include <stdint.i>

%inline %{
#include <cstdint>

namespace ns1::ns2 {
    struct Person {
        char name[32];
        uint8_t age;
    };
    static constexpr Person PERSONS[] = {
        {"Ken", 8},
        {"Cat", 27}
    };
}
%}

%include <carrays.i>
%array_functions(ns1::ns2::Person,arrayPerson);
```

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> test.arrayPerson_getitem(test.PERSONS,1).name
'Cat'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wish one day, swig can offer something more "natural" that user can just access element like test.PERSONS[0]...

Comment: Actually, one more question related to the same code snippet above.  If I add a `const` cv-qualifier to member variables name and age, it seems like SWIG generates some invalid code (the cv-qualifier in this case is valid tho) that I got this error, `error: use of deleted function ‘ns1::ns2::Person::Person()’` and `3096 |     return (new ns1::ns2::Person[nelements]());`  Seems like SWIG always tries to allocate a new object when returning even though I requested for returning a reference.

Comment: @HCSF if you want more natural try using a `std::vector` instead of an array.